# iOS: disable bounce scroll but allow normal scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, css, mobile-safari

I don't want the content of my site sloshing around when the user hits the edge of a page. I just want it to stop.

The omni-present javascript solution I see everywhere is this:

```
$(document).bind(
   'touchmove',
   function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
);
```

But this prevents scrolling entirely. Is there way to just remove the bounce. Preferably with CSS or a meta tag as opposed JS, but anything that works will do.

Answer (score 21):

I have to add another answer.
My first approach should work, but, there is an iOS bug, which still bumbs the whole page, even if e.stopPropagation.

mikeyUX find a workaround for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16898264/2978727
I wonder why he just get a few clicks for this great idea...

This is how I used his approach in my case:

```
var content = document.getElementById('scrollDiv');
content.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    this.allowUp = (this.scrollTop > 0);
    this.allowDown = (this.scrollTop < this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight);
    this.slideBeginY = event.pageY;
});

content.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    var up = (event.pageY > this.slideBeginY);
    var down = (event.pageY < this.slideBeginY);
    this.slideBeginY = event.pageY;
    if ((up && this.allowUp) || (down && this.allowDown)) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: still not satisfied with the answer ?

Comment: Missing ) on the last line ;) Also, didn't work for me , as my element is only visible when you click the modal - damn iOS :(

Answer (score 12):

Disable bouncing by prevent the default behaviour of the document:

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Allow scrolling by prevent that the touch reaches the document level (where you would prevent the scrolling):

```
var scrollingDiv = document.getElementById('scrollDiv');
scrollingDiv.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Mind the difference between these two:

```
event.stopPropagation()
event.preventDefault()
```

StopPropagation should be your choice here !
Here is a very good explanation:
http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-events

Edit:
Same problem, same solution:
[document.ontouchmove and scrolling on iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798201/document-ontouchmove-and-scrolling-on-ios-5/7888335#7888335)

Edit2:
fixed typo in variable names
added brackets after methods

Comment: I tried making that switch and it doesn't seem to prevent the bounce. I'm on an iPhone5 with iOS6.

Comment: Thats right. Guess I misunderstood your question. I edited my post to show the full solution.

Comment: I don't know much about event propagation in iOS, so it's not obvious to me what the final code should be from your answer. Do you mind clarifying what the final code snippet should look like to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: There is nothing more. Replace 'scrollDiv' with your div-ID you want to be able to scroll and call the lines in the first two boxes above in a '$(document).ready' function, or whereever you want after the site has been loaded.

Comment: oh, and '$(document).bind()' is quiet the same in jquery as 'document.addEventListener()' _in this case_ ...

Comment: I tried this, but it did not prevent bouncing on iPhone5s - I did find a way using 
http://gregsramblings.com/2012/05/23/preventing-vertical-scrolling-bounce-using-javascript-on-ios-devices/

and then adding swipe detect to make a scroll - however the scroll effect was soo poor, so I decided to just live with the bounce

Answer (score 8):

If apply to Desktop Browser, don't need any JavaScript codes, just few lines of CSS codes:

```
html {
    height  : 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    height  : 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: This stops the bounce effect in Android Chrome too.

Comment: This stops the bounce effect on my iOS Chrome browser but I lose the smooth scrolling "flick" effect. The scrolling becomes quite choppy and doesn't decelerate towards a stop.

Answer (score 5):

I tried lots of different approaches I found here on stackoverflow, but iNoBounce was the thing that really worked for me:
https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce

I just included it in my index.html:

```
<script src="inobounce.js"></script>
```

Comment: But there ins't anything else to do.. :|
It solved the question's problem which was exactly like mine.

Comment: If that is the case then you are all set. I did not downvote or flag it.

Comment: It's not removing completely the bounce effect but it's doing really good job :)

Comment: I did this to make it work properly I applied it to a wrapper div which has all the content in

Answer (score 5):

iOS 16 started support of css overscroll-behavior.
If you are targeting > iOS 16 devices (including its WKWebview), to prevent overscroll bounce, the solution is simple

add following CSS

```
html {
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

Tested in iOS 16 and above.

Comment: Working also in iOS PWA application

Answer (score 3):

[This library](https://github.com/timbartsch/no-bounce) is solution for my scenarios. Easy way to use just include library and initialize where you want like these;

```
noBounce.init({   
    animate: true
});
```

If you want to prevent bouncing only on one element and not on the whole page you can do it like:

```
 noBounce.init({
    animate: true,
    element: document.getElementById("content")
  });
```

Comment: This disables all scrolling... so kind of useless? but maybe I didn't use it right...

Answer (score 0):

Found a code that worked to me, I believe it will work to you.

The solution is written here: http://apdevblog.com/optimizing-webkit-overflow-scrolling/

Basically, you need to have this js code:

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready, false);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", function (evt)
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    function ready()
    {
        var container = document.getElementsByClassName("scrollable")[0];
        var subcontainer = container.children[0];
        var subsubcontainer = container.children[0].children[0];

        container.addEventListener("touchmove", function (evt)
        {
            if (subsubcontainer.getBoundingClientRect().height > subcontainer.getBoundingClientRect().height)
            {
                evt.stopPropagation();
            }
        }, false);
    }
```

And then, have your scrollable divs with the class="scrollable".

Answer (score 0):

After trying these suggestions and reading several articles, the fix for me was to use the CSS property < overflow-x: hidden; > on the problematic element/container.