# Prevent touchStart but allow click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

I would like to prevent `touchStart` events in order to prevent Safari from bouncing in iOS devices under certain conditions.

To do so I'm using the folowing:

```
$('.wrapper').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But now none of the click events work on it:

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', function() {
    $('.wrapper').text('Click fired');
});
```

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/8n47whd0/4/)

I can not replace the `click` event for any other one. As this might come from the end user.

Previously to iOS 10, the bouncing [could be avoided by preventing only `touchMove`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461485/ios-disable-bounce-scroll-but-allow-normal-scrolling) but since iOS 10 it will bounce unless `touchStart` is prevented too.

Is there any way to prevent only the `touchStart` event but allow the use of the `click` event?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have iOS 10 available for a test-drive, and this is a wild guess, but check this snippet:

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
  if (e.type != 'click') {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    $('.wrapper').text('Click fired');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">asd</div>
```

Comment: Nop, not working. It seems to fire always the `touchStart` before the `click` one. Therefore it prevents the click.

Comment: How about changing the `click` to `mousedown`?

Comment: As i said, that's not an option. Developers can use any event they want and will very probably use `click`. 
Found a work around. But looks more like a hack :D I trigger the click event on the event target after preventing the default: https://jsfiddle.net/8n47whd0/5/

Comment: @Dekei not sure if that would solve the problem. But not interested in adding such a "big" script anyway.

Comment: Ok. It seems like a known issue, so this script might also fix some other problems you might haven't think about, yet.

Comment: The purpose of the library is to prevent delays. Which might or might not be a possible solution to my problem. But still, it seems to me an overkill to add such a script to solve this specific problem.