# How to resolve vertical scrolling issues in iPhone for overflow-x:hidden

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, html, responsive-design

I have embedded the following code snippet to avoid horizontal scrolling in my responsive website on iPhone portrait view when we switch orientations i.e from landscape to portrait:

```
html, body { width:100%;  overflow-x:hidden;}
```

But now not only horizontal scroll is disabled in iPhone but also vertical scrolling. This issue is found only on iPhone.

Please provide a solution for the above.

Comment: can you provide the fiddle or url to page

Comment: To disable horizontal scroll add max-width:100%;

Comment: also this may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128196/iphone-html5-app-scrolling-question

Comment: None of the above worked.